# What does "Take the disguise" mean?

Tags: meaning, grammar, word-usage

I was reading this particular [sentence](http://books.google.com/books?id=HF0m3spOebcC&pg=PA83&dq=%22took+the+disguise+of%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=vaCAUYHSL-rJiwLdo4C4Bw&ved=0CFsQ6AEwCTgU#v=onepage&q=%22took%20the%20disguise%20of%22&f=false):

> She ***took the disguise*** of an old woman and came to Eleusis, where she was welcomed by the family of King Celeus.

*Disguise* means costume. So, does it mean she took an old lady's clothes?

Comment: It means that she pretended to be an old woman.

Comment: 'Disguise' does not mean 'costume', it means to alter the appearance of something to deceive a third party. Military camouflage disguises people/tanks/aircraft as part of the landscape.

Answer (score 2):

No! The verb *take* has various uses and senses. *She took the clothes of an old woman* would have the sense you mean, but *take* is not infrequently used 'delexically' - as a sort of 'dummy', bleached-of-semantic-content verb; the expressions where this happens are really fixed idioms. Examples are:

> He took ( / had) a bath.
>
> Take the next right.
>
> Do you feel like taking a walk?
>
> She took the disguise of an old woman (ie she disguised herself as an
>   old woman).
>
> DNA actually takes the form of a double helix.

But note that the delexical - lexical distinction can get blurry:

*Sauron took the form of a mighty warrior clothed in armour.*

Here, 'take the form' implies an electing to exist in this form at this time, so take is not just a verb bleached of meaning here. This is true also with 'take the disguise (of)'.