# Meaning of the term "empty use" in the context of modal verbs

Tags: meaning-in-context, terminology, modal-verbs

I'm reading a book titled *Comprehensive High School English Grammar & Composition*. The author, who is Indian, says this on the use of the modal verbs *can* and *could*:

> *Can* is used to express "empty use":
>
> 1. I *can* walk.
> 2. I *can* feel summer heat.
> 3. Birds *can* sing in the trees.
>
> *Could* is used to express "empty use":
>
> 1. I *could* feel the touch of cool breeze.
> 2. They *could* enjoy soothing showers.

But I'm not getting what the meaning of the phrase "empty use" is, and why the author used this term here, and whether it's a standard term or concept, or unique to this (non-native) author.

Is "empty use" a recognized term among linguists? If so, what does it mean?

Comment: What information gives "empty use"?? Can/could can express ability and possibility. When using a grammar it is necessary to be able to judge whether the grammar you use is helpful or not. Use another grammar.

Comment: I have certainly never come across the term before, and I have absolutely no idea what it is supposed to mean. I also find at least three of those example sentences quite strange, and at least one of them downright ungrammatical. Is this is a book specifically about Indian English? Or is it supposed to be about English in general? If the latter, then I would stop reading it right now and get yourself a better one.

Comment: My take is "empty use" means the author doesn't understand how modal verbs are used, and assumes you could omit them from those example sentences without changing their meanings. If he does think that, he's wrong, of course (and he should also have used the standard term "dummy" rather than "empty").

Comment: This is wrong. You can argue that *I can feel summer heat*, *I can see the ocean*, and *I could feel the touch of a cool breeze* are "empty uses" because they mean almost exactly the same thing as *I feel summer heat*, *I see the ocean*, and *I felt the touch of a cool breeze*. However you can't delete *can/could* in the other examples without changing the meaning. You can tell that whoever wrote those phrases isn't a native speaker of standard English, because they wrote *of cool breeze* rather than *of a cool breeze*.

Comment: I suspect the author saw something like *I can feel summer heat* used as an example of an "empty use" or "dummy use", and decided to make up more of his own examples without really understanding the concept. Otherwise, how could he have gotten two of the five examples correct?

Comment: Ditch the book. Look on ELU for modal usage, but this will take some time. You'll have to (1) find them all and (2) sort out the level they're pitched at – don't start with one of tchrist's '100 usages of the modal X'.

Comment: Let me add that when *can* or *could* is used with a verb of sensing, it seems to me that it often really is a dummy use. For example, the sentences *"I can see the ocean from here,"* *"I see the ocean from here,"* and *"I am seeing the ocean from here,"* all mean the same thing, except that a native speaker is much more likely to use the first. Why? Somebody who understands grammar better than I do will have to answer this.

Comment: @PeterShor We use the first because it emphasizes the novelty and value of the *ability* to see the ocean from our present position. The other two constructions do not express that. And we don't use the present progressive because we're not interested in the temporal aspect.

Comment: @PeterShor Yes; there is an obvious (if not complete) semantic bleaching (for the usual meaning) with 'I can hear the birds singing in the garden' as opposed to 'I can hear the birds singing in the garden if I turn the radio down.'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I am unfamiliar with the term "semantic bleaching"; can you elaborate a bit on what you mean?

Comment: @Dan: I don't think that's quite true. There are lots of times when I would say *"I can see ..."*, *"I can hear ..."*, and *"I can feel ..."* when I'm not really emphasizing the fact that I am able to see, hear, or feel ...  Certainly Ngrams shows that the French use *"je peux voir le ..."* a lot less frequently than the English use *"I can see the ..."*

Comment: @Dan Bron It's an accepted term (when a lexical word becomes used in a formulaic way so that it becomes (to all intents and piurposes) a function-word; there are mentions on ELU, amongst which I try to introduce the term gently  in addressing [delexical verbs](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/112927/what-does-take-the-disguise-mean/112931#112931).

Comment: ... [Nordquist](http://grammar.about.com/od/ab/g/Bleaching.htm) has his usual good introduction. 'It was a terribly good show' is another example where meaning is (at least largely) forgotten.

Comment: YOu had better get a different book. That one seems to be full of the author's (and the author's teachers') favorite myths and terminology. Certainly "empty use" is a useless term -- what can it possibly mean?

Comment: @John Lawler 'Making the most sound'? (Like a modal yacht.)

Comment: Never mind the duplication. LOOK AT JOHN LAWLER'S 'ANSWER'.

Comment: Most usages of *can* with sense verbs are "empty uses", but not all of them. For example *"I can smell things that are too faint for other people to notice"* is a sentence where it really does mean *"am able to".*

Answer (score 2):

Can/Could is a modal, a type of auxiliary verb that is used to indicate modality – that is, to indicate likelihood, ability, permission, or obligation.

But in 'I can smell burning', the author is really merely expressing what he smells, not his ability to do so (in the more usual usage). 'I can smell burning' is same as 'I smell burning' (although the former is by far the more usual way of expressing this, and sounds more natural). See the difference in this usage? Here, 'can' is just an extra/dummy word that may be omitted without changing the meaning. Hence, the term 'empty use' (though John Lawler's terminology is better). Similarly with the other two sentences. You can omit the 'can/could' and they still make sense.

Comment: Sense verbs and verbs involving producing and understanding languages are the same whether or not they're preceded by a `Possible`-style modal. Thus _I can speak Spanish_ is the same as the generic _I speak Spanish_, and _I can smell smoke_ is the same as the present _I smell smoke_. One more strange modal fact; English has thousands.