# How did the verb "take" come to mean "to undertake and make, do, or perform"?

Tags: word-usage, etymology, expressions, history, delexical-verbs

One of the senses of the verb *take* is:

> to undertake and make, do, or perform.
>
> - *take a walk*
> - *take aim*
> - *take legal action*
> - *take a test*
> - *take a look*
>
> [*sense 17a*, [*Merriam-Webster*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/take)]

It is an idiomatic usage. Some common examples are, as shown above, *take a walk* and *take a look*. How did the verb "take" develop this sense?

This would also explain why people say "take a dump" rather than "give a dump". To the porcelain gods, perhaps.

Comment: "Some ppl take a sh*t, some ppl give a sh*t", as they say.

Comment: One of the senses of the verb _take_ is "to undertake and make, do, or perform" (See the sense 17a in [MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/take)). It is just an idiomatic usage. Some other familiar examples are _take a walk_ and _take a look_.  The more interesting question could be "How did the verb "take" develop this sense?".

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm asking.

Comment: You could possibly edit the question title and body with the details I've provided and your additional findings, and it can have a chance to be re-opened. You can check the link for the close reason for more info. Another option could be asking a new question with good enough details.

Comment: @ermanen it does seem to me that you can't `take` every verb like walk and look. It seems like that kind of phrase has certain verbs it can / can't apply to.

Comment: Take here is followed by a noun, not a verb: take a look, take a walk, take a choice, take a decision, take a vacation, take a detour, take a try, take a bite... I think it can be used with most (if not all) nouns that refer to an action. And not sure there's much semantic difference between using take+noun and using an equivalent verb (look, walk, choose, decide, vacation, detour, try, bite...).

Comment: See also [What does _take the disguise of a_ mean?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/112927/what-does-take-the-disguise-mean/112931#112931) This usage is delexical (semantically bleached).

Comment: The verb **take** enters Old English from Old Norse **taka**. The Scandinavian verb is extremely productive. In brief, the physical meaning of "to seize in one's hand" develops a broader abstract sense of "to commence an action"  and from there "to do, perform, engage in an action" (broadly conceived). The Norse word entered the language with those meanings already established.

Comment: That sounds like another answer

Comment: Essentially, _take_ in this construction has become bleached, as Edwin suggests. It's now a part of a host of constructions and has no meaning -- _take a shit_ involves no taking at all, rather the opposite (though _give a shit_ has a rather different meaning). So _take a walk/run/piss/train/powder_ have nothing to do with dictionary meanings, since it's the construction that has the meaning, not the verb. You might as well look up _the_ in the dictionary and try to figure out English article use from that.

Comment: That may be an answer then also.

Comment: There is also usage like, "take my wife, please"

Comment: @JohnLawler Which isn't to say you can't trace the construction historically, and see that it's been around for at least 1000 years, and also recognize variants like *He **took to** laughing and couldn't stop.*  It's more like a spiral tie-dye than a bleaching :-)

Comment: _Put, take, go, come, bring,_ and a number of other ordinary small verbs have been used to extend expressions and mark constructions ever since English has lost its inflections.

Answer (score 3):

[*OED*](https://www.oed.com/dictionary/take_v?tl=true) mentions that the sense "to make, do, perform (an act, action, movement, etc.); to carry out." of the verb *take* is a periphrastic usage and the earliest citation for this sense is from *c*1380:

> Often *take* forms with the object a phrase which is a periphrastic equivalent of the cognate verb: e.g. *to take a leap* is equivalent to *to leap*, *to take a look* to *to look*, *to take one's departure* to *to depart*, etc.
>
> <sub>Oxford English Dictionary, s.v. “take, v., sense IX.83.a”, July 2023. https://doi.org/10.1093/OED/8480914419</sub>

And for the etymology, *OED* says that the French verb *prendre* may have influenced the development of additional senses of the verb *take*:

> French *prendre* to take (see **prend** *v.*) is attested in a similar range of senses, some of which appear to have influenced the semantic development of the English verb.
>
> **take** *v.* also occurs in a large number of idiomatic phrases which correspond to (and in many cases are influenced by) parallel constructions in French with *prendre*. For further discussion see L. Iglesias-Rábade in D. A. Trotter *Multilingualism in Later Medieval Brit.* (2000) 93–130.
>
> <sub>Oxford English Dictionary, s.v. “take, v., Etymology”, July 2023. https://doi.org/10.1093/OED/4265677235</sub>

Note: *Prend* is an obsolete, rare verb in English meaning "To take; (also) to understand, comprehend." from 1447, per [*OED*](https://www.oed.com/dictionary/prend_v?tab=meaning_and_use#28549802).

---

<sub>I'll try to check the given source in *OED* or other sources, and add any additional findings.</sub>